# Handling objects of different classes in a derived List<T> class

Tags: c#

I have several classes (A, B, C, ...) that all use a `List<AnotherClass>` to store references to 'other' objects. But 'other' is different for each of the classes A, B, C.
So
Class A contains `List<Class_X>`
Class B contains `List<Class_Y>`
Class C contains `List<Class_Z>`

Instead of implementing Add / Delete / Search (etc) functions in A, B, C it seems logical to me to create a class `ListRef<T>` from `List<T>`

```
public class ListRef<T>: List<T>
{
    protected ListRef<T> ListOfObjects = null;
    protected string name = null;

    public ListRef<T>
    {
        ListOfObjects = new ListRef<T>();
    }
}
```

Using the code above (is this the right code for what I want?) I don't know how I can supply the right class (Class_X, Class_Y, Class_Z) replacing/specifying `<T>` in the constructor of each class (A, B, C) that will use ListRef.

In the constructor of class A I would like to write something like:

```
public A() : base<Class_X>
{
}
```

How can I specify from WITHIN class A what kind of objects need to be stored in ListOfObjects?

I prefer NOT to write

```
public A()
{
    ListOfObjects = new ListRef<Class_X();
}
```

as I would like to have ListOfObjects declared **private** instead of **protected**

---

Inside Listref I JUST want to be able to Add, Delete, Search objects. So I'm not actually using those classes (Class_X, Class_Y, Class_Z).

currently I have

```
public class A
{
     private List<Class_X> ListOfObjects = null;
     A()
     {
         ListOfObjects = new List<Class_X>();
     }

     public void Add(string Name)
     {
        Class_X Object = new Class_X(Name);
        ListOfObjects.Add(Object);
     }
     public void Delete(Class_X Object)
     {
        ListOfObjects.Remove(Object);
     }
}
```

and the same kind of code for class B (using Class_Y)   and for class C (using class_Z).
To me it seems logical to use ONE class  ListRef to perform the Add and Delete operations and maintain the list for all classes I use.
(of course the real code is more complicated)

Comment: Why are you inheriting from List and then using your subclass inside your class? This seems to be quite circular.

Comment: It might help if you showed how you are using this class so we get a better understanding of what you're trying to make it do.

Comment: Inside Listref I JUST want to be able to Add, Delete, Search objects. So I'm not actually using those classes (Class_X, Class_Y, Class_Z). Currently I have

    public class A
    {
         private List<Class_X> ListOfObjects = null;
         A()
         {
             ListOfObjects = new List<Class_X>();
         }

         public void Add(string Name)
         {
            Class_X Object = new Class_X(Name);
            ListOfObjects.Add(Object);
         }
         public void Delete(Class_X Object)
         {
            ListOfObjects.Remove(Object);
         }
    }

Comment: hmmm comments are hard to read here if containing code; I will add it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, it sounds like what you want to do is create a group of classes A, B, C, etc.. that each manage a collection of some other type (X, Y, Z) - but you don't want to duplicate some of the list management logic across A, B, and C.

There are two different ways to achieve this.

**First, the inheritance approach:** you could give A, B, and C a common generic base class that is parameterized on the type of the item each will manage. Here's a code example:

```
public abstract class ABCBase<T>
{
   protected IList<T> m_List = new List<T>();

   // methods that manage the collection
   // I chose to make the virtual so that derived 
   // classes could alter then behavior - may not be needed
   public virtual void Add( T item )    { ... }
   public virtual void Remove( T item ) { ... }
   public virtual int  Find( T item )   { ... } 
}

public class A : ABCBase<X> { ... }

public class B : ABCBase<Y> { ... }

public class C : ABCBase<Z> { ... }
```

**Second, is the composition approach:** create a manager class for your colleciton that implements the operations on the child list, and aggregate that in each of A, B, and C:

```
public class ListManager<T>
{
   private IList<T> m_List = new List<T>();

   public void Add( T item )    { ... }
   public void Remove( T item ) { ... }
   public int  Find( T item )   { ... }
}

public class A
{
   public ListManager<X> ListOfX { get; protected set; }

   public A() { ListOfX = new ListManager<X>(); }
}

public class B
{
   public ListManager<Y> ListOfX { get; protected set; }

   public B() { ListOfY = new ListManager<Y>(); }
}

public class C
{
   public ListManager<Z> ListOfX { get; protected set; }

   public C() { ListOfX = new ListManager<Z>(); }
}
```

**You could also choose to mix both of these approaches -** creating a list management class but also creating base class (or interface) for A, B, C - so that each exposes a consistent property ChildList (or some such) that consumers could use without always having to know the type actual types A, B, C.

Comment: Yes, you understood my question correctly.

I don't want(can) to use the inheritance approach as one of the classes (B) has been derived already and multiple inheritance isn't allowed in C#   (of course I can solve that by introducing still another class).

The composition approach seems better for me, although I have to use 
       ListOfX.Add(item);
instead of just
       Add(item);

Any idea how I can avoid that?

Comment: If you just want this for syntactic purposes, define an interface that A, B, and C implement with the Add(), Remove(), Find(), methods etc. And forward the call into the ListManager aggregated instance. It's a little clunky, but I think that's the best you can do if you can't change the inheritance trees for A,B,C.

Comment: Thanks for answers(s) . IMO it is the best (I can't 'vote' yet) and I'm using the composition method now. In fact it also has advantages using public ListManager<X> ListOfX   as it makes it more clear what kind of list is maintained and used compared to ListOfObjects.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would recommend doing it...

```
public class ABC_Base<TChild>
{
    public IEnumberable<TChild> Children { get; set; }

    public void AddChild(TChild item) 
    {
    }

    public void RemoveChild(TChild item)
    {
    }

    //etc
}

public class A : ABC_Base<X> // X is the type for your child
{

}

//Used like so...
A myA = new A();

myA.AddChild(new X());

// or if you are wanting to specify when created then this...

public class A<TChild> : ABC_Base<TChild>
{
}

//Used like so...
A myA = new A<X>();
A myOtherA = new A<Y>();

myA.Addchild(new X());
myOtherA.AddChild(new Y());
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
public interface ISomeOtherClass
{
}

public class Class_X : ISomeOtherClass
{
}

public class Class_Y : ISomeOtherClass
{
}

public class BaseClass<T> where T : ISomeOtherClass
{
   public ListRef<T> OtherObjects { get; set; }
}

public class A : BaseClass<Class_x>
{
}

public class B : BaseClass<Class_Y>
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am correctly understanding your problem.  Here is how I would do it:

```
interface ILetter<T>
{
    IList<T> OtherObjects { get; }
}

class A : ILetter<Class_X> 
{
    public IList<Class_X> OtherObjects
    {
        get { /* ... */ }
    }
}

class B : ILetter<Class_Y> 
{
    public IList<Class_X> OtherObjects
    {
        get { /* ... */ }
    }
}

// etc...
```

With this interface you can be sure that each type has a public `IList<T>` property that you can use for any operations you wish.